# How to programmatically trigger next step when the WorkItem is completed when using Design Automation API?

Tags: python, rest, autodesk-designautomation

I'm developing an application using Forge API that would require getting an output .txt file, and somehow download the log file, after running a WorkItem through Design Automation.

For context, after I call POST 'CreateWorkItem', I use the WorkItem `id` from the response to query the WorkItem status with GET 'WorkItemStatus'.
(Obviously, 'CreateWorkItem' and 'WorkItemStatus' are representation of a request URL)

I get something like this when I call GET 'WorkItemStatus':

```
{
    "status": "inprogress",
    "stats": {
        "timeQueued": "2023-03-06T08:18:10.5864042Z",
        "timeDownloadStarted": "2023-03-06T08:18:10.8429977Z"
    },
    "id": "74ffb56b0b2646d7b83f631357107fbe"
}
```

and when the WorkItem is finished, GET 'WorkItemStatus' returns something like this:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/<report_uri>",
    "stats": {
        "timeQueued": "2023-03-06T08:18:10.5864042Z",
        "timeDownloadStarted": "2023-03-06T08:18:10.8429977Z",
        "timeInstructionsStarted": "2023-03-06T08:18:15.2964064Z",
        "timeInstructionsEnded": "2023-03-06T08:20:28.6748982Z",
        "timeUploadEnded": "2023-03-06T08:20:29.2015653Z",
        "timeFinished": "2023-03-06T08:20:29.8129396Z",
        "bytesDownloaded": 146477075,
        "bytesUploaded": 231936
    },
    "id": "74ffb56b0b2646d7b83f631357107fbe"
}
```

Here's the issue: Because of the requirement for repeatedly calling GET 'WorkItemStatus', I can't just do 'await' for the API response.

Now,

I wish to find a more efficient way to retrieve the status. I'm implementing it with a while-loop like so:

```
import time
import requests
import json

# initial GET status
res = requests.get(url_workitem_status, headers=headers).text
status = json.loads(res).get('status')

# Repeat until Get FAIL or SUCCEED status
while (status == "inprogress"):
    res = requests.get(url_workitem_status, headers=headers).text
    status = json.loads(res).get('status')
    time.sleep(300) # 5 minutes interval
```

I'm writing the program in Python 3 for now, and could use JS if there's a better way there. Though I'm not as well-versed in JS so hopefully I could get some of your help with that too.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize callback mechanizm of Design Automation instead of busy loop. If you specify call-back url in workitem specification Design Automation server notify to the URL when the workitem is completed. Also you can set additional infomation, e.g. workitemId, output bucketid and .etc, as call back URL parameter.

Unfotunately, I don't have python example but the call back mechanizm is programing language independent, so you can know how it works with below  tutorial and API reference.

https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/design-automation/execute-workitem

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/callbacks/

Please note that you need your own web-server and global url to get the call back notification from Design Automation Server. So you need to ustilize URL forwarding tool, e.g. ngrok, in local developemnt. This point is also described in above tutorial page.

Hope this will help to resolve your issue.